# Python for loop implementation when I make dataframe with Pandas module

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, web-crawler

I am interested in learning python but I learned python program for 2 weeks. I coded this program for 2 days but I can't find how I should do. This is the code that I did as follows.

===========================================================================

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/naver_datalab.csv",sep=",", encoding ='CP949')

df1 = df['키워드']

for i in df1:


r=requests.get("https://search.shopping.naver.com/search/all.nhn?query=" + str(i) + "&cat_id=&frm=NVSHATC")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")


all=soup.find("li",{"class":"snb_all on"}).text

all2=all.replace("전체","").replace("\s", "").replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")

df['ProductN'] = all2


print(df)
```

============================================

First, I read csv file with Pandas and dataframe is as follows.

```
 df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/naver_datalab.csv",sep=",", encoding ='CP949')
```

키워드

0  모기퇴치기

1  벌레퇴치기

2  해충퇴치기

3  전기모기퇴치기

================================================================================
The expecting result page is as follows.

print(df) -> enter key

키워드         ProductN

0  모기퇴치기     132,877

1  벌레퇴치기     127,250

2  해충퇴치기     136,109

3  전기모기퇴치기  125,307

===============================================================================
However, actual result page of `print(df)` is as follows.

C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe

C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled/test1.py

```
   키워드 ProductN
```

0    모기퇴치기  132,877

1    벌레퇴치기  132,877

2    해충퇴치기  132,877

3  전기모기퇴치기  132,877

```
   키워드 ProductN
```

0    모기퇴치기  127,250

1    벌레퇴치기  127,250

2    해충퇴치기  127,250

3  전기모기퇴치기  127,250

```
   키워드 ProductN
```

0    모기퇴치기  136,109

1    벌레퇴치기  136,109

2    해충퇴치기  136,109

3  전기모기퇴치기  136,109

```
   키워드 ProductN
```

0    모기퇴치기  125,307

1    벌레퇴치기  125,307

2    해충퇴치기  125,307

3  전기모기퇴치기  125,307

Process finished with exit code 0

================================================================================
I don't know how I can fix this result. I just assume that from the for loof, there are some mis-implementation.
Please let me know how can I fix this result.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also it is probably hard for a big part of this website audience to visually compare strings with non-latin characters, so you might want to avoid using these (or use them as little as possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `df['ProductN'] = all2` you assign all2 to the whole column, but you want to assign it to just one cell. So change this line to:

```
df.loc[df['키워드'] == i, 'ProductN'] = all2
```

Comment: I spend more than 2 days but I can't know how to do, but with your comment, I can solve this problem. Thank you very much~!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer was helpful, please consider accepting it: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to accept your comment, but I came here 3 days ago, so I don't know how to do it. I click the check box but I don't know it works.